# How to include AngularJS in a page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, npm, pug

I'm making a NodeJS application and I want to use AngularJS for my client side scripting. I downloaded AngularJS via NPM and now I'm trying to get it implemented within my page, for some reason my requite isn’t working. Can anyone help me include the AngularJS file?

**Post page.**

```
extends layout
block content
  script(src="/javascripts/postCtrl.js")
  // Page Content
  .container(ng-app='postModule', ng-controller='postCtrl')
    form(method='post')
      button(ng-click='test()') Click to test Button
```

**Post script**

```
var angular = require('angular');
var app = angular.module('postModule', []);
app.controller('postCtrl', function ($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.test = function(){
    alert("Working");
  };
});
```

Comment: what does you layout look like?
you should use `express.static` to serve it and include it at the end of your `<body />`

Comment: @malix is correct. In your rendered html you need a `<script src="link to your local angular file or CDN"></script>`

Comment: @KarlGalvez . Well i downloaded the module, and i would like to call it out of that location, instead of downloading the file and putting it in my JavaScript file.

Answer (score 1):

client side javascript does not support `require`. Before you put `postCtrl.js` into your front-end page, you should use `babel` or `webpack` to compile it into client side executable javascript